# How to solve error: Incorrect or no genesis block found. Wrong datadir for network?

Tags: bitcoind, currencies, ubuntu, merkle-tree, block-hash

I am making my own alt-coin, and I have mined the first genesis block hash(after some time), Merkle hash, nnonce and time. I am running on Ubuntu14.04.

But when I run ./bitcoind I get this error

> Error: Incorrect or no genesis block found. Wrong datadir for network?

What does it mean? how do I fix it?

Here is debug.log shows:

> ```
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Booducoin version v0.8.7.4-gc1e46ab3a90b-beta ()
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Using OpenSSL version OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Default data directory /home/boodu/.booducoin
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Using data directory /home/boodu/.booducoin
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Using at most 125 connections (1024 file descriptors available)
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 init message: Verifying wallet...
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 dbenv.open LogDir=/home/boodu/.booducoin/database ErrorFile=/home/boodu/.booducoin/db.log
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Bound to [::]:9333
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Bound to 0.0.0.0:9333
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 init message: Loading block index...
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Opening LevelDB in /home/boodu/.booducoin/blocks/index
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Opened LevelDB successfully
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Opening LevelDB in /home/boodu/.booducoin/chainstate
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Opened LevelDB successfully
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 LoadBlockIndexDB(): last block file = 0
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 LoadBlockIndexDB(): last block file info: CBlockFileInfo(blocks=1, size=241, heights=0...0, time=2018-04-01...2018-04-01)
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 LoadBlockIndexDB(): transaction index disabled
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 LoadBlockIndexDB(): hashBestChain=5e55391ddfe7258c5d1dc5ebf2c8ce9bdec72edf482f171a6cb04416c53be9b8  height=0 date=2018-04-0$
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Error: Incorrect or no genesis block found. Wrong datadir for network?
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Shutdown : In progress...
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 StopNode()
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Flushed 0 addresses to peers.dat  3ms
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Committing 0 changed transactions to coin database...
> 2018-04-02 18:33:04 Shutdown : done
> ```

Comment: Can you paste debug.log content?
Anyway it looks like your daemon isn't able to find the desired path to the blockchain data folder. If you can post your debug I could maybe give you a more precise solution.

Comment: @Cluster2k  Please check the debug.log

Comment: Try delete /home/boodu/.booducoin folder and restart daemon.

If not working maybe you have some errors in the code itself or in the genesis hash generation process.
If you need more help to fix it please contact me at cluster2k@protonmail.com or on this thread: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=3196213.0

Regards.

Comment: @Cluster2k Yes, it's working after I delete /home/boodu/.booducoin folder. Thank you so much!

Comment: i'll put my comment as an answer below, please mark as answered if you can.

Comment: @Cluster2k Can you help me in another error of forming gitian build

Comment: contact me at the email address i provided or open a new question, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question**:

> when I run ./bitcoind I get this error

```
Error: Incorrect or no genesis block found. Wrong datadir for network?
```

**Answer**:

Delete /home/boodu/.booducoin (~/yourcoinname/.yourcoindatadir) folder and restart daemon.